# Call DateTimePicker.ValueChanged event in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, events, event-handling, datetimepicker

I have created the below code to let my users see how many records have been printed of the total that will be returned when a search is run using current form selections.

I've got my code functioning for when the value changes for my DateTimePicker control (different conditions, new query, new record count). Now I'm trying to call and run this same code event when my combobox control named `cmbLetterType` has it's selected value changed.

```
private void dtpDate_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // If not first run when form loads and sets dtpDate to current value.
     string qryCmd = "";
     OdbcDataReader dr;

     if (cnt > 1)
     {
         switch (cmbLetterType.SelectedIndex)
         {
             case 0:
                 docType = "oldAddr";
                 qryCmd = buildSearchQuery(docType);
                 break;
             case 1:
                 docType = "newAddr";
                 qryCmd = buildSearchQuery(docType);
                 break;
             case 2:
                 docType = "nameChg";
                 qryCmd = buildSearchQuery(docType);
                 break;
         }

         var newQry = qryCmd.Replace(qryCmd.Substring(0, qryCmd.IndexOf("FROM") - 1), "SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT");
         var orderByIndex = newQry.IndexOf("ORDER BY");
         newQry = newQry.Replace(newQry.Substring(orderByIndex, newQry.Length - orderByIndex), "");

         dr = mdl.GetData(newQry);
         while (dr.Read())
         {
             lblNumPrinted.Text =  "# out of " + dr["COUNT"].ToString() + " printed";
         }

         // NEED TO PERFORM ANOTHER QUERY COMBINED WITH BAC000PF to see how many records have not been printed.



         mdl.closeConn();
         lblNumPrinted.Visible = true;
     }
     cnt++;
}

private void cmbLetterType_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ERROR ~~~~~~~~~
    dtpDate.ValueChanged();
}
```

When I type `dtpDate.ValueChanged();` however, I receive: `The Event 'System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker.ValueChanged' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=`? Can anyone help me with this; pretty sure I'm overlooking something very basic.

I suppose absolute worst case I could completely copy the code, but that just seems like a bad idea when it comes to possible future maintenance.

Comment: Have you tried just hooking up the event? `dtpDate.ValueChanged += new EventHandler(dtpDate_ValueChanged);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy!

Just take everything inside your event-handler `dtpDate_ValueChanged` and put it in another function... give it a good, descriptive name. Now call it from both places! ;)

```
private void dtpDate_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoTheStuff();
}

private void cmbLetterType_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoTheStuff();
}

private void DoTheStuff()
{
    // Code goes here...
}
```

Comment: *FACEPALM* ~ Thanks Jeff. Nothing like Finals week to fry your brain and make you ask stupid questions :X

Comment: Just by chance, any thoughts on capturing when a different radio button inside a group box has been selected? I've got a group called "Print Options" with 2 radio buttons and another group called "Systems" with 3 radio buttons that I'd like to fire the same code when the value in the group is changed.

Comment: You can have a single event-handler attached to the same event on multiple objects. I think you'd probably have to handle the `RadioButton.CheckedChanged` event of each radio button. You just add handler with `+=` multiple times. You can probably check the `sender` property to see which `RadioButton` it came from. Also beware that changed the `Checked` property in your program will fire the event as well.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I think I hear what you're saying. Any way you could show me an example?

Comment: I think it's something you can do in the designer... where you assign event-handlers to events, you'd just assign the same method for the same event on each control.